# how to assign empty to string array in c#

Tags: c#

How can I assign empty to string array in c#?

```
string [] stack; //string array
```

how to assign

```
stack = ""; //this statement gives error cannot implicitly convert to type string to string []
```

Comment: You can't. An array is not a string. Do you mean put an empty string in each element of the array?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot use:

```
string[] stack = "";
```

Since stack in here is an array of string. If you want to initialize empty string for each elements in array, you can use LINQ with `Enumerable.Range` to get the result, assume there are 10 items in here:

```
 string[] stack = Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
                            .Select(i => string.Empty)
                            .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 3):

This will create an array with three empty strings.

```
string[] arr1 = new string[] { "", "", "" };
```

or if you only need one:

```
string[] arr1 = new string[] { "" };
```

or another example (with 3 strings):

```
string[] arr1 = new string[3];
arr1[0] = "";
arr1[1] = "";
arr1[2] = "";
```

Answer (score 3):

Just iterate over the array like this:

```
int length = stack.Length;
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    stack[i] = string.Empty;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to create empty array of string[] object.

```
string [] stack = new string[]{};
```

Answer (score 0):

Now you can use `string[] stack = ["", "", ""];`.

The `[]` at right-hand-side is called "**collection expression**".
You can initialize any collection type with this syntax sugar. Like:

```
List<Foo> Foos = []; // An empty list.
```